# Book with only unique Sahih ahadith

Tags: hadith, books

Has anyone made a summary of Sahih Al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim which does not contain duplicate ahadith, that is, containing only one hadith out of different versions?If yes, please tell me its name.

Comment: Are you looking for a book containg the ahadith of one sahih without duplicate or of both sahihs without duplicate?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Either will work. Preferably one book with unique ahadith from both of them. So, for example, if there are three versions of a hadith in Bukhari and four in Muslim, it should have just one version. But if there are two books, one with unique ahadith from Bukhari and another with unique ahadith from Muslim, that's fine too.

Answer (score 2):

Salih Ahmad Ash-Shami mentioned in the introduction to Jami Usul At-Tis'ah that the Hadith Bukhari and Muslim agree on are 1,873. Bukhari has 801 not reported in Muslim and Muslim has 1,222 not reported in Bukhari. Together they have 3,896 reports without repetition. See either Jami Bayn As-Sahihayn by Al-Humaydi or the same text by Salih Ahmad Ash-Shami. In English the closest thing is Muhsin Khan's Lulu Wal-Marjan which is what they agree on but not the individual reports that occur with each of them.

Comment: If al-Lu'lu' wal-Marjan اللؤلؤ والمرجان  is an English version of [Muhammad Fu'ad 'Abdulbaqi's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Fuad_Abdul_Baqi) book then it contains 2006 ahadith on which al-Bukahri and Muslim agreed.